# Having a class static method with same name as another class

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

Here is the example :

```
struct A
{
    A(const int a ):b(a)
    {
    }

    int b;
};

struct B
{
    B() : a(5)
    {
    }

    static void A()
    {
    }

    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B::A();
}
```

And the compiler error is :

```
a9.cpp:19: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
a9.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
a9.cpp:24: error: class ‘B’ does not have any field named ‘a’
```

I am using gcc 4.3.0 on fedora 9.

Can someone explains why is the compiler complaining?
If possible, with references from the standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```
struct B {
    B() : a(5) { }

    static void A() { }

    ::A a;
};
```

Since you've used `A` as a member name in `B`, that member's definition shadows the `A` type from the outer namespace. Using `::` you can get to that namespace.

This behavior is specified in the [(draft) standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) as:

**3.3.7 (1)** "A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in a nested declarative region" (the definition of `struct B`, which is nested in the namespace where `struct A` is also defined).

Carefully read the introduction to chapter 3, Basic concepts, for further clarification. Especially, this section specifies that

**3 (7)** Two names are the same if

- they are identifiers composed of the same character sequence; or
- they are the names of overloaded operator functions formed with the same operator; or
- they are the names of user-defined conversion functions formed with the same type.

Note that this last definition does not distinguish between types and class members, so the name hiding (shadowing) rule 3.3.7 (1) applies.

Comment: Yes, I figured out the hard way that the static method name shadows the class name, but is it the code or compiler bug? Also, can you tell where in standard is that stated?

Comment: I added some standardese that I think explains this behavior. It seems very natural to me that your code does not work.